# Expression Result Unused in iOS UIAlertView

Tags: ios, string, uialertview

I'm still a newb with iOS and I'm a little stuck creating an alert view combining regular text and variables. I'm getting an "expression result unused" warning on the initWithTitle line and I don't know how to fix it.

```
name = @"foo";

//now create the alert
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle: (@"Hello %@", name)
                        message: @"You're looking mighty fine today"
                        delegate: nil
                        cancelButtonTitle: @"I'm awesome"
                        otherButtonTitles: nil];

//show the alert
[myAlert show];
```

Right now, with the warning, everything compiles but my alert title is just "foo" instead of "hello foo".

If I remove the parentheses I get a syntax error on the next line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the title as follows:

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                    initWithTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@",name]
                    message: @"You're looking mighty fine today"
                    delegate: nil
                    cancelButtonTitle: @"I'm awesome"
                    otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that you have to format the string with that stringWithFormat method rather than just creating one willy nilly like I'm used to in other languages.